# Angular httpClient returns property does not exist on object

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get('url').subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
     console.log(data.login);
   });
  }
}
```

Here, I can see the data with login in console but I get an error saying property login does not exist on data. Is there a workaround for this without using an interface? Because the data I want to get is pretty huge and will probably be modified in the future, so is there any better way?

Comment: can you add the value printed by console.log(data)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **[docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response)** state when using `HttpClient`...

> ```ts
>  this.http.get('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
>    // Read the result field from the JSON response.
>    this.results = data['results'];
>  });
> ```
>
> In the above example, the `data['results']` field access stands out because you use bracket notation to access the results field. If you tried to write `data.results`, TypeScript would correctly complain that the Object coming back from HTTP does not have a `results` property. That's because while `HttpClient` parsed the JSON response into an Object, it doesn't know what shape that object is.

So your options are to either type your response (which both docs and I would suggest), or then use the bracket notation.

Typing the response would be to create an interface/class, which you tell that it is what you expect from the request:

```ts
export interface MyResponse {
  results: // your type here
}

this.http.get<MyResponse>('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
   this.results = data.results;
 });
```